# How to open ROM files using SWF on Chromebook. (Specifically .nes and .gba right now)

Tags: google-chrome-os, swf, rom

I have a collection of .gba and .nes files that I would like to play on a Chromebook. This Chromebook is managed, And while I am allowed to use it however I want, I can't download APK files and stuff. I originally had an SWF reader that integrated with drive, but that site doesn't work anymore. Is there a way I can play my ROMS In-Browser on ChromeOS?

Sorry for the poor formatting, first time posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/olahol/melody-jsnes this doesn't work for everyone. If it doesnt work for you then I don't know what to do. Something else similar is http://copy.sh/ which is really cool. I recommend looking at it.

Comment: Explaining HOW to use these tools will make this a better answer. Right now this is just a comment suggesting a few alternatives, but the lack of explanation means it is not really an answer yet.

Comment: The github site describes how to run the file. I just posted the link so they knew it existed.

Comment: Thar makes this a "link only answer", and also disallowed. Please read the Help section to better understand how this site works. If that link changes your answer will no longer be valid. You answer must make an attempt, at least, to remain relevant for the foreseeable future.